# Not equal (<>) Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, sql-delete

How can I write:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblB WHERE [Field1]) <> 'YES' "
```

3 records are found when I write:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblB WHERE [Field1]) = 'YES' "
```

I assume that the condition is being validated if a field is blank

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Thank you for your suggestions. I had to use IS NULL

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblB WHERE [Field1] IS NULL"
```

Comment: Huh? I'm not following. Have you tested `IS NULL`?

Comment: what is the question?  where are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to delete all rows where `[Field1] <> 'YES'`, including those where `[Field1] Is Null`, you can add another condition to the `WHERE` clause.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblB WHERE [Field1] <> 'YES'" & _
    " OR [Field1] Is Null"
```

Or you can use the `Nz` function in a single `WHERE condition.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblB WHERE Nz([Field1], '') <> 'YES'"
```